# Como criar sub pastas para controllers, model e view no Phalcon?

Tags: phalcon-php

Estou procurando uma forma de colocar níveis de pastas na estrutura de models, views e controllers. A estrutura que eu quero montar seria a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já olhei e implementei esse [link](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/simple-subcontrollers) mas não funcionou. O retorno do erro é o seguinte:

```
meuApp\Controllers\SegurancaController handler class cannot be loaded
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('meuApp\Contr...', 2)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->_dispatch()
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#3 C:\Projetos\meuApp\Source\public\index.php(42): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#4 {main}
```

Alguma sugestão de como implementar?

Comment: Não posso afirmar que este é o problema, mas geralmente em linux tudo é case-sensitive, talvez o Phalcon também seja case-sensitive para facilitar a portabilidade entre linux, mac e linux.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, desconfiei disto, mas coloquei tudo em letras minúsculas, somente a primeira maiúscula e nada surtiu efeito...

Comment: Pode ser o namspace que esta errado, poste o seu routes, porque pelo nome `meuApp\Controllers\SegurancaController` parece estar bem errado :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento realmente tinha erro nas rotas e nos nomes... acabei de ajustar, e parou o erro! obrigada!

Comment: Imaginei pelos nomes, que bom.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigido as rotas o problema foi resolvido.

Os nomas das rotas não estavam compatíveis com o arquivo router.php